# I am trying to write a function in python that takes user input and stores it in a list

Tags: python

right now I believe I have started off the loop correctly but for some reason it stops after two iterations, and when I print the list, there are no values.
I know its a really beginner question, but I am really having trouble with this.

```
def string():
    """Grabs user input and stores it in a list"""
    vegies = []
    choice = None

while choice != "Q":
    choice = input("Please select a vegetable or fruit to the list or Q to quit:")
    vegies = vegies.append(choice)
```

Comment: dont name your function `string()`

Comment: And what is the real question?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are doing `veggies = veggies.append(something)`.
The method `append` does not return any value, so it is wrong to write `variable = list.append()` once, as it won't return anything, `variable` will hold `None` as value.

In order to use append, use only `veggies.append(something)`

```
def string(): #Although not wrong in terms of syntax, it is not recommended to name the function 'string'
 """Grabs user input and stores it in a list"""
    vegies = []
    choice = None

    while choice != "Q":
        choice = input("Please select a vegetable or fruit to the list or Q to quit:")
        vegies.append(choice)
```

Answer (score 0):

A much easier route (Note : I am using `python 2.7.9`, you are using `python 3.x` so just substitute `raw_input` with `input`

```
vegies = raw_input('Enter vegetable or fruit seperated by spaces: ')
print vegies.split(' ')
```

Output:

```
Enter vegetable or fruit seperated by spaces: apple banana orange
['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
```

You can very do `veggie_list = vegies.split(' ')` to store the list and carry on with your program

Comment: Thank you very much....now to pass this info into another function to be manipulated, or vice versa....